# RequireJS libraries load slowly in Spring MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, spring-mvc, requirejs

I have put RequireJS into my Spring MVC application for the purpose of dependency management for my libraries.  I am using jQuery and jQuery UI, among others. I've got it working, but whenever I load/refresh the page, the page will first show without any of the libraries having been loaded (everything appears incorrectly), and then the page will flash and everything will appear correctly. Is that normal?  Here is what I have so far:

**main.js:**

```
require([ "jquery-1.8.3", "jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom", "newsearch" ], function() {

});
```

**mysearch.jsp:**

```
<%@ page session="true"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>MyApp</title>

<!-- CSS is loaded here -->

<!-- JavaScript -->
<c:url value="/resources/scripts/main" var="main" />
<c:url value="/resources/scripts/require-jquery.js"
var="require" />

<script data-main="${main}" src="${require}"></script>

...
```

**newsearch.jsp:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        // JS Code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below usually works fine with Spring MVC for me. Note that the $(document).ready(...) call would be at the bottom of mysearch.jsp.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path/to/require-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path/to/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        require(["${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path/to/a-dependency.js", 
                 "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path/to/another-dependency.js"],

            function() {
              console.log('Page dependencies loaded...');
              // More initialization code...
            }
        );              
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks ialencar, so you're saying that the <script> block containing the $document.ready(...) should go at the bottom of mysearch.jsp? Doesn't it need to be in a <head></head> block? Also, I'm getting a console error that "ReferenceError: $ is not defined on $(document).ready(function() {", any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming that mysearch.jsp is having formatting issues, if so the document $(document).ready(...) should go at the bottom of it. The error you are getting means jQuery was not loaded properly.

Comment: Sorry for all of my questions, I'm just confused as to how jQuery can be loaded if it is being loaded by RequireJS INSIDE the $(document).ready(...) function. Wouldn't it need to be loaded OUTSIDE of it, first?

Comment: You're right, my example above won't work. Sorry. I just edited, now it should work, but jQuery will no longer be managed by RequireJS.